# Migrated CVS to new server - but where have the branches and versions gone?

Tags: migration, cvs

I tar'd the repository folder (including the CVSROOT) and copied it to the new server, then un-tarred it.  When I connect to CVS via Eclipse, I can get the sourcecode, however the server is not providing the versions, branches or history.

Is there some extra step I might have missed?

Comment: Have you checked permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following commands (using user 'cvs' and repository folder 'repository') and now the branches, tags and versions are available.

```
chown -R cvs repository
chgrp -R cvs repository
chmod -R 775 repository
chmod -R +s repository
```